# Unable to scroll down on a pop up message - Gmail Sign In

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate sign in page of gmail. Once I enter all the mandatory details like user name, pass, DOB, email etc and click on Next Step button, I got a pop up message which needs to scroll down till the end and then Accept button will be enabled.

I am unable to scroll down the pop up page. Below is my code

```
//import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window;

public class GmailSignIN {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

//maximize browser
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='FirstName']")).sendKeys("Krishna");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LastName']")).sendKeys("Krishna");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GmailAddress']")).sendKeys("Krishna.Krishna1154");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("04Mar1989@");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PasswdAgain']")).sendKeys("04Mar1989@");


//Input the month
List<WebElement> month_dropdown = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div"));
//iterate the list and get the expected month
Thread.sleep(3000);
for (WebElement month_ele:month_dropdown){
String expected_month = month_ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");
// Break the loop if match found

Thread.sleep(3000);
if(expected_month.equalsIgnoreCase("August")){
    month_ele.click();
    break;
}

driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":3")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthDay']")).sendKeys("14");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthYear']")).sendKeys("1988");

driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":e")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RecoveryPhoneNumber']")).sendKeys("xxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RecoveryEmailAddress']")).sendKeys("xxxxx@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton")).click();

String myWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle);

driver.findElement(By.id("tos-scroll")).click();

//Initialize Javascript executor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

//Scroll inside web element vertically (e.g. 100 pixel)
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.id("iagreebutton")), 300);



    } }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwLqe.png)

Comment: You might want to remove your personal information

Answer (score 0):

This Works:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='FirstName']")).sendKeys("Krishna");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LastName']")).sendKeys("Krishna");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GmailAddress']")).sendKeys("Krishna.Krishna1154");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("04Mar1989@");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PasswdAgain']")).sendKeys("04Mar1989@");
    //Input the month
    List<WebElement> month_dropdown = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div"));
    //iterate the list and get the expected month
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    for (WebElement month_ele:month_dropdown){
    String expected_month = month_ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    // Break the loop if match found

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    if(expected_month.equalsIgnoreCase("August")){
        month_ele.click();
        break;
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(":3")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthDay']")).sendKeys("14");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthYear']")).sendKeys("1988");

    driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(":e")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RecoveryPhoneNumber']")).sendKeys("4694222863");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RecoveryEmailAddress']")).sendKeys("sonal.kumar123@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton")).click();


    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tos-scroll-button']/div/img")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your just need to replace `driver.findElement(By.id("tos-scroll")).click();` in your code with `driver.findElement(By.id("tos-scroll-button")).click();`, as  the correct value for **id** attribute of desired control is 'tos-scroll-button'. Additionally, you can remove following lines from your code, as they are not needed:

```
//Initialize Javascript executor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

//Scroll inside web element vertically (e.g. 100 pixel)
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];
```

For scrolling in other scenarios, you can use following code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
//For scroll down
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
//For scroll up
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks or you response and its scrolling down but its not scrolling down till the end o the page. Once this scroll down till the end then only "I Accept" button will be enabled.

Comment: I tried below code also to double click but its not scrolling till the end

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("tos-scroll-button"))).doubleClick().build().perform();